# SWIFT reflect all implementations of a certain protocol

Tags: swift, reflection, protocols

I want to use SWIFT reflection to resolve all implementations of a certain protocol.

The problem I'm trying to solve is that I want to test all present and future implementations of a certain protocol.

The reflection in SWIFT is limited, but after reading up on it, I believe it should be possible. I have found the following articles on reflection in SWIFT, but I am having trouble mapping it in to my specific use case.

https://nshipster.com/mirror/
https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/reflection-in-swift/

How can I resolve and iterate over all implementations of a specific protocol?

```
protocol Animal {
    var color: UIColor { get }
    var name: String { get }
}

class Cat: Animal {
    var color: UIColor = .red
    var name: String = "Joshua"
}

class Dog: Animal {
    var color: UIColor = .blue
    var name: String = "Anna"
}

class TestAnimals {
    func testAnimals() {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: Animal.self)

        for child in mirror.children {
            print(child.value)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean you want to test the implementation of a protocol? Your goal here is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition says: `Reflection` is a common programming language feature that enables us to inspect, and work with, the **members** of a type — dynamically, at runtime. `Members` are list of properties inside a class/struct.

So, if you want to iterate over all your types that confirm `Animal` protocol, you need to have them as **members** in a type, and then iterate over it.

Check code below-:

```
protocol Animal {

    var name: String { get }
}

class Cat: Animal {
    
    var name: String = "Joshua"
}

class Dog: Animal {
    var name: String = "Anna"
}

class TestAnimals {
    var cat:Cat
    var dog:Dog
    
    init(cat:Cat,dog:Dog) {
        self.cat = cat
        self.dog = dog
    }
    
    func testAnimals() {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        
        for child in mirror.children {
            if let animal = child.value as? Animal {
                print(animal.name)
            }
        }
    }
}


var obj = TestAnimals(cat: Cat(), dog: Dog())
obj.testAnimals()
```

Or, you could also do something like below, by making composition.This allows you to assign any `Animal` type at runtime.

```
    class TestAnimals {
        var myAnimal:Animal
        
        
        init(animal:Animal) {
            myAnimal = animal
        }
        
        func testAnimals() {
            let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
            
            for child in mirror.children {
                if let animal = child.value as? Animal {
                    print(animal.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
       let objects :[Animal] = [Cat(),Dog()]
       for myobj in objects{
       let obj = TestAnimals(animal: myobj)
       obj.testAnimals()
```

Comment: What exactly are you testing here?

Comment: @joakim Danielson from my understanding as OP mentioned "How can he resolve and iterate over all implementations of a specific protocol? In that case it's Cat and Dog that he wants to iterate over, and print required details of that type, like Name.

Comment: But what are you testing actually?

Comment: The OP wants to test Swift Reflection feature, and in his case he want to iterate over protocol implementations using reflection and test if he can print the value, and also any future implementation of that protocol. That's what I understand so far.

Comment: Well let’s see if OP comes back with any feedback because that doesn’t make much sense to me.

Comment: Hi. Thank your for your suggestion. After reflecting a bit my self... I seem to have misunderstood what I can do with reflection. I was under the impression that I also could get implementations of a protocol. But as you've stated it only gores for members og an object. Thank you for clearing that up.
Since my question was me misunderstanding "reflection" I grant that your response actually replies to what I initially asked.